# Python if statement with multiple condition is messing up?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I'm a beginner with Python. I have a 2-d array called infected that stores values that correspond with the index. This bit of code is messy, but basically what I'm trying to do is simulate an infectious disease spreading over a number of days (T). The individual is infectious for infTime many days and then goes into recovery where they are immune for immTime days. There's also a probability value for whether a node will be infected and a value for how many nodes they will be connected to.

My problem is that I'm also trying to track the number of individuals currently susceptible, infected, or immune, but something is going wrong in the elif statement that is marked "# Messing up in this loop". Currently, the program is running through the statement more times than it should, which is throwing off the variables. If I switch the conditions in the elif statement, the program doesn't go through it and will stay at a very low number of infected individuals the entire time. I'm really stuck and I can't find any reason why it's not working how I want it to.

Code:

```
# Loop through T days, checking for infected individuals and connecting them to beta num of nodes, possibly infecting
infTime = 5 # Time spent infected before becoming immune
immTime = 20 # Time spent immune before becoming susceptible again
numSus = N - count
day = 0
while day < T:
    for a in range(len(infected)):
        nextnode = random.randint(0, N-1)
        if((infected[a][0] == 1) and (infected[a][3] < infTime)):
            num = infected[a][1]
            for b in range(num-1):
                if((a != nextnode) and (infected[nextnode][0] == 0)):
                    infected[a][3] += 1
                    chance = round((random.uniform(0, 1)), 2)
                    if(infected[nextnode][2] > chance):   
                        infected[nextnode][0] = 1
                        G.add_edge(a, nextnode)
                        count += 1
                        numInf += 1
                        numSus -= 1
                elif((a != nextnode) and (infected[nextnode][0] == 1)):
                    G.add_edge(a, nextnode)
        elif((infected[a][0] == 1) and (infected[a][3] == infTime)): # Messing up in this loop
            infected[a][3] = 0
            infected[a][4] = 1
            numImm += 1
            numInf -= 1
            G.add_edge(a, nextnode)
        elif((infected[a][0] == 0) and (1 < infected[a][4] < immTime)):
            infected[a][4] += 1
        elif((infected[a][0] == 0) and (infected[a][4] == immTime)):
            infected[a][4] = 0
            numImm -= 1
            numSus =+ 1
    day += 1
    print("Number of infected on day ", day, ": ", count)
```

Comment: _the program is running through the statement more times than it should, which is throwing off the variables_ What exactly does that mean?  Do you mean that `elif` statement is true more often than you expect?

Comment: Yes, it's determining that the conditions of the elif statement are true when they're not. It's supposed to run through only when infected[a][0] == 1 and infected[a][3] == infTime, but it's doing it when infected[a][3] is greater than infTime, too.

Comment: _it's doing it when infected[a][3] is greater than infTime, too_ No, it isn't.  There's nothing magical about that `elif` statement.  It is triggering because the given condition is true.  If you don't believe me, put `print(infected[a][0], infected[a][3])` as the first line in the `elif` block.  You'll see.